# How to convert array of object to nested object and vise versa in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nest-nested-object

Array of objects where the hierarchy objects is stored in hierarchy
property. nesting of objects are done based on this hierarchy

```
[  
  {
    "hierarchy" : ["obj1"],  
    "prop1":"value" 
  },
  {  
    "hierarchy" : ["obj1","obj2"],  
    "prop2":"value",  
    "prop3":"value"  
  },  
  {  
    "hierarchy" : ["obj1","obj3"],  
    "prop4":"value",  
    "prop5":"value"  
  },  
  {  
    "hierarchy" : ["obj1","obj3", "obj4"],  
    "prop6":"value",  
    "prop7":"value",  
    "arr"  :["val1", "val2"]  
  }
]
```

Expected nested object, hierarchy key removed here

```
{  
  "obj1":{  
    "prop1":"value",  
    "obj2" : {  
      "prop2":"value",  
      "prop3":"value"  
    },  
    "obj3":{  
      "prop4":"value",  
      "prop5":"value",  
      "obj4" : {  
        "prop6":"value",  
        "prop7":"value",  
        "arr"  :["val1", "val2"]  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Code I tried but at line 8 unable to get the hierarchy

```
var input = "nested array as above";  
var output = {};  
var globalTemp = output;  
for(var i = 0 ; i<input.length ; i++){  
  var tempObj = input[i];  
  for(var key in tempObj){  
    if(key == "hierarchy"){     
      globalTemp = globlalTemp[tempObj[key]] = {};  
    }  
  }  
}  
console.log(globalTemp);
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I'l add what i've tried, I am unable to approach the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a newer version of javascript, you could use restparameters for the wanted value key/value pairs and build a nested structure by iterating the given hierarchy property by saving the last property for assigning the rest properties.

The reclaimed part `getFlat` uses an array as stack without recursive calls to prevent a depth first search which tries to get the most depth nodes first.

At start, the stack is an array with an array of the actual object and another object with an empty `hierarchy` property with an empty array, because actually no key of the object is known.

Then a `while` loop checks if the stack has some items and if so, it takes the first item of the stack and takes a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for getting an object `o` for getting back all key/value pairs and another object `temp` with a single property `hierarchy` with an array of the path to the object `o`.

The `push` flag is set to `false`, because only found properties should be pushed later to the result set.

Now all properties of the object are checked and if

- the value is truthy (to prevent `null` values),
- the type is an object (`null` is an object) and
- the property is not an array

then a new object is found to inspect. This object is pushed to the stack with the actual path to it.

If not, then a value is found. This key/value pair is added to the `temp` object and the flag is set to `true`, for later pushing to the result set.

Proceed with the keys of the object.

Later check `push` and push `temp` object with `hierarchy` property and custom properties to the result set.

```js
function getFlat(object) {
    var stack = [[object, { hierarchy: [] }]],
        result = [],
        temp, o, push;

    while (stack.length) {
        [o, temp] = stack.shift();
        push = false;
        Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(o[k])) {
                stack.push([o[k], { hierarchy: temp.hierarchy.concat(k) }]);
            } else {
                temp[k] = o[k];
                push = true;
            }
        });
        push && result.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

var data = [{ hierarchy: ["obj1"], prop1: "value" }, { hierarchy: ["obj1", "obj2"], prop2: "value", prop3: "value" }, { hierarchy: ["obj1", "obj3"], prop4: "value", prop5: "value" }, { hierarchy: ["obj1", "obj3", "obj4"], prop6: "value", prop7: "value", arr: ["val1", "val2"] }],
    object = data.reduce((r, { hierarchy, ...rest }) => {
        var last = hierarchy.pop();
        hierarchy.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, r)[last] = rest;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    reclaimedData = getFlat(object);

console.log(object);
console.log(reclaimedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina thanks for the reply, I'm trying to understand "getflat" function. Could you please explain the code if possible. please tell me how did you approach this problem.

Comment: what do you mean with *"how did you approach this problem"*? actually i wrote a recursive function and then i found a wrong order (read: different than the given) and wrote another function without recursive parts.

Comment: I mean the approach is very nice, I never did like this. I just wanted to understand how did you break the problem and solved it with only few lines. Thankyou

Comment: it's an iterative process to think about some approaches. but you have to iterate the keys of the object and look if nested objects exists, that is the frame. the consiteration of a stack based approach vs an recursive approach come from a try out and a check if the result matches the wanted result. by recursive approach, the first key is pushed at last to the result array, but with a breadth-first search, you get the wanted result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` and `reduce` methods and inside create shallow copy of current object and delete `hierarchy` property.

```js
const data = [{"hierarchy":["obj1"],"prop1":"value"},{"hierarchy":["obj1","obj2"],"prop2":"value","prop3":"value"},{"hierarchy":["obj1","obj3"],"prop4":"value","prop5":"value"},{"hierarchy":["obj1","obj3","obj4"],"prop6":"value","prop7":"value","arr":["val1","val2"]}]

const result = {}
data.forEach(function(o) {
  o.hierarchy.reduce(function(r, e) {
    const clone = Object.assign({}, o);
    delete clone.hierarchy
    return r[e] = (r[e] || clone)
  }, result)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code, it will be very helpful. Treat me as newbee

Comment: Hey nenad, I've gone through reduce method, pretty much understood code. Can you give some pointers for reverse conversion(nested obj to arr of obj).